# Can you hoard an unlimited amount of supplies?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

There are four different single-use supplies in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, the Cobra Missile launcher, Medi-Gel, Ops Survival Pack and the Thermal Clip Pack:

[image]

Until now I've just been hoarding them, but I wonder if there is some maximum limit of those supplies I can stash? Can I collect as many as I want of the supplies, or am I wasting the new supplies I get from packs at some point, because my inventory is full?

Answer (score 3):

The limit is 260 per item from what I've seen.  I had 258 missiles and got the equipment pack with +5 missiles and it only went to 260.

Answer (score 3):

For the supplies the maximum is 255. I have not seen 260, but maybe it is a console difference. For xbox 360, at least, it is 255.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In Mass Effect 3 there is a fixed inventory limit of 150 items in multiplayer. This can be changed through coalesced modding, but with the default game it's 150.

**If you decide you want to coalesced mod, do so at your own risk. You risk being banned from multiplayer as well as messing up the game. Consider yourself warned.**

Go to Mass Effect3\BioGame\Config in your installation folder then open DefaultParty.ini

There's a line that says

> m_nMaxInventoryItems = 150

You can change this to increase your inventory.

(Source: BioWare forums)
I tried it and it works. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Be warned that Coalesced modding -  especially Coalesced modding that has *any* impact on Multiplayer, has a decent chance of getting you banned from Multiplayer by EA at some point.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of this as I have explained the risks of coalesced modding in my other answers. Not only do you risk being banned, but it is also very easy to mess up the game. I was just pointing out how to coalesced mod in case the OP decided he/she wanted to.

Comment: Indeed. But for stuff like this, a disclaimer belongs everyplace it's recommended. :)

Comment: OK, added one. Will do in the future. I was not recombination it at all, to clarify. I think it's a bad idea, just giving the option. But I will add disclaimers in the future.

Comment: That entry doesn't seem to be the limit for supplies in multiplayer, I now have 158 of them without any messing around in the config files.

Comment: Ok. Well, this is the supply limit. Singleplayer, multiplayer, I'm not sure what supply limit it is for, as I can't read source code and game files. It was designed to be able to change supply limits and other stuff in ME2 that was limited. So, there's no supply limit in ME3 multiplayer. Ok! That is your answer.